# Simulink Set sample time the same as Data

Tags: matlab, time, time-series, simulink, fuzzy-logic

I am trying to make a simulation in Simulink, with the fuzzy model.
As inputs, I have set four time series variables from the workspace (compatible to simulink after performing Simulink.Timeseries function): every row of the variables has a linked time starting from 0 to 10566 (seconds, I believe). How can I set the sample time in simulink source block in order to pick every exact case without interpolation?
Thank you for your kind answers,
Phalaen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using the [From Workspace](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/slref/fromworkspace.html) block? If so, it's simply a matter of specifying the sample time in the block parameters and unticking "Interpolate data". You can also display the sample time information of the model to check which sample time each block is using, see [View Sample Time Information](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/ug/how-to-view-sample-time-information.html) in the documentation.

Comment: Yes, I am using the From Workspace block, but, in the setting ot the block, a Sample time is request and, from the documentation, I am not able to find the right string to write there...

Comment: Yes, enter whatever sample time you are using for your data. If you don't know what sample time is used for your data, I'm afraid no block can help you...

Comment: Thank you am304, I have a timeseries with 10566 value, from 0 to 10566 integers (seconds), I have tried to use [1, 0] as sample time, but the output has only 11 values..

Comment: Well then it sounds like your sample time is 1s. What is your stop time? By default, it's 10, so you would need to change that to 10566 if you want the entire timeseries to be processed.